# Proof that a curve is differentiable

Tags: derivatives, parametric, curves

We consider the following curve in the interval $\psi:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3 $,

$$\psi(t) = \left(\frac{1}{3}(1 + t)^{3/2},\frac{1}{3}(1 - t)^{3/2}, \frac{1}{2}t\right)$$

I would prove that the slope of **each** element as it approaches zero ist the same in both directions and that it is continuous at $t = 0.$

Is there a specific method to prove the differentiability of a curve or is my assumption correct?

Comment: Show that all its coordinates functions are differentiable... I really don't know what "slope of each element" could possibly mean.

Comment: @DonAntonio by slope of each component I mean the "two-sided hypotetical derivative": $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\psi_j(t_0 + h) - \psi_j(t_0)}{h}$$ for each $j $ exists, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, thank you. In fact your coordinate functions are all of them differentiable everywhere in $\;(-1,1)\;$ , so that gives you differentiability of $\;\psi\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio I found out, with the formula I posted above it doesn't quite work out for the first two components, how do I go about proving the differentiability at $t = 0$ for those two components?

Comment: Those are pretty well known functions... for example, with the first one: $$f_1'(t)=\left(\frac13\left(1+t\right)^{3/2}\right)'=\frac13\frac32(1+t)^{1/2}=\frac12\sqrt{1+t}\implies f_1'(0)=\frac12$$This is very basic stuff...

Comment: @DonAntonio I honestly didn't know that the derivative itself is the proof of the existence of the derivative at a specific point ... Thanks !!

Comment: Unless some additional conditions are given, what else could it be?

Comment: @DonAntonio  I don't know, the thing is the formula is then useless since it's  almost always faster to take the derivative than to use the formula...

Comment: I honestly don't understand. It is my opinion that whoever deals with curves like yours (probably within differential geometry) has already to have studied basic calculus. The definition is one thing, *how we usually work out stuff* is another thing. We don't **usually** go to limits and stuff to differentiate. That'd take lots of time and effort. We have theorems (arithmetic of limits and/or of continuous/differentiable functions, chain rule, squeeze theorem, L'Hospital rule and etc.).  **Only** if specifically requested by a teacher, or if nothing else works, we go to limits...